# How to find key in array?

Tags: php, arrays, linux

I have a large array [3744] (read in from file).
Array key always changes, and does not have the same value.

**First run Blu-Ray:**

Output 0: [55] => TINFO: 0,10,0, "36.9 GB"

**Second DVD:**

Output 1: [135] => TINFO: 0,10,0, "5.7 GB"

but part of the edition is "TINFO: 0,10,0," always the same.

**How can I search my array for "TINFO: 0,10,0," to get the array key, would be happy?**

```
<?php 
   $size=shell_exec("sudo makemkvcon -r info dev:/dev/sr0 | grep -i 'TINFO:0,10,0,'");
   $size=substr($size, 14, -2);
?>
```

Output is perfect, but with multiple queries it takes a long time, so I've saved the entire output in file.

```
<?php 
    $BD_Info_array = file("../BD_Info");
    $key = array_search('TINFO:0,10,0,', $BD_Info_array);
    echo $BD_Info_array[$key];
?>
```

Here I get the first line of the file, it's not what I want.

```
MSG:1005,0,1,"MakeMKV v1.14.3 linux(x64-release) started","%1 started","MakeMKV v1.14.3 linux(x64-release)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it that way:

```php
/// get size
$lines = file('../BD_Info');
$searchstr = 'TINFO:0,10,0,';

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if(strpos($line, $searchstr) !== false) {
        $size[] = $line;
    }
}

echo $size[0];                  //// OUTPUT > TINFO:0,10,0,"36.9 GB" 
echo substr($size[0], 14, -2);  //// OUTPUT > 36.9 GB
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the first line of the file because `array_search()` returns boolean `FALSE` if it can't find what you're looking for in the array, so `$key` is being set to FALSE. Then, when you do `echo $BD_Info_array[$key];`, `$key` is being interpreted as the integer `0`, so you basically get the same result as doing `echo $BD_Info_array[0]`.

You should use the identity operator `===` to check if `$key` is really `FALSE` before printing the line:

```php
if ($key === FALSE) {
  echo "Line not found!";
}
else {
  echo $BD_Info_array[$key];
}
```

As for why `array_search()` isn't finding your line, it works differently than grep. It will look for an item in the array that has that *exact value* as the value. If you want your PHP code to just find a line which contains that substring, you'll want to iterate through the array created by `file()` and use `strpos()` to find the line - but note that `strpos()` also returns `FALSE` if it doesn't find a match, and a numerical value (which may be 0 and therefore evaluate to `FALSE`) if it does.